# Did quandl end cme data on June 30th 2022?

Tags: r, xts, quandl

```
library(Quandl)
library(xts)

Quandl.api_key("your_api_key")

cl <- Quandl("CME/CLU2022", type = "xts")
```

This data ends on June 30th 2022. As of today 7/14/2022, it should have data out to 7/13/2022. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same issue.  I have seen no price updates past June 30, 2022.

Unfortunately, it looks like NASDAQ has acquired Quandl and they are in the process of deprecating the CME EOD price database/API.

From Nasdaq data support:

> Kindly be advised that the free CME futures database has been
> deprecated. Moving forward, the data will no longer be updated and may
> no longer be accessed. We're very sorry for any inconvenience caused
> by the deprecation of the free CME futures database and we don't have
> an equivalent database available on Nasdaq Data Link at the moment.
>
> Please note that free data feeds may get deprecated at any time for
> various reasons eg. they may no longer meet our quality standards,
> they get copyrighted, technical issues prevent us from obtaining the
> data, etc.
>
> Unfortunately, we do not have a similar database on Nasdaq Data Link
> that may serve as an alternative.